# Return to first step in program

Tags: python

after the user enters the wrong data, I would like enter the data again again.

```
a=int(input("enter the value: "))
b=int(input("enter the value: "))

def d(a,b):
    if(b == 0):
        return "back to menu"
    else:
        return a / b
print(d(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to use a while loop, such as:

```
b = 1
while b != 0:
    a=int(input("enter the value: "))
    b=int(input("enter the value: "))
print(a,b)
```

you will probably have to change `b != 0`  to a more suitable conditiuon for your code, but this should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
b=0
while(a!="what you want" && b!="what you want"): 
     a=int(input("enter the value: "))
     b=int(input("enter the value: "))
```

you need to change after the"=" to whatever you want